# Resampling data in dataframe with weighted averages

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with time-based data and I need to resample it by 12-hour and day periods. So far I'm using the following code:

```py
if self.resample_by == 'day':
    self.model_df = self.model_df.resample('D', on='index').mean()
    self.model_df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
elif self.resample_by == 'shift':
    delta = dt.timedelta(hours=12)
    self.model_df = self.model_df.resample(delta, on='24h_day_start').mean()
    self.model_df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
else:
    pass
```

Right now as you can see I'm using `mean()` on resampled data as a stopgap, but in reality different rows have different weights so I need to do a weighted average calculation instead.

As I understand the problem what I need is to write a function to calculate weighted averages and then use `apply(func)` instead of `mean()`. Correct?

What I do not understand, however, is how to structure my function, because I'm confused with what `DataFrame.resample` actually returns. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) says that the function returns a *resampler object*. Anyone knows what this object is and how I can use the output in a weighted averages function?

Or maybe there's another approach I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the `groups` property.

```
rs = df.resample(...)

for group_name, group_labels in rs.groups.items():
    vals = rs.get_group(group_name)
    # apply weighted average function to vals df
```

Full documentation on Resampler object at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/resampling.html

Comment: Thank you for the information! This worked like a charm!